# AWS DynamoDB Java SDK how to see if Point-in-time recovery (PITR) is enabled on table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, recovery

Would like to figure out how I can get to know if PITR is enabled.

for AWS Java.

checked for PointInTimeRecoverySpecification but no succes. Neither did using TableDescription.

Comment: Try [describeContinuousBackups](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#describeContinuousBackups(software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DescribeContinuousBackupsRequest)) whose response will give you continuousBackupsDescription, which represents the continuous backups and point in time recovery settings on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can use `DescribeContineousBackupsRequest`:

> Checks the status of continuous backups and point in time recovery on
> the specified table. Continuous backups are ENABLED on all tables at
> table creation. If point in time recovery is enabled,
> PointInTimeRecoveryStatus will be set to ENABLED.
>
> After continuous backups and point in time recovery are enabled, you
> can restore to any point in time within EarliestRestorableDateTime and
> LatestRestorableDateTime.
>
> LatestRestorableDateTime is typically 5 minutes before the current
> time. You can restore your table to any point in time during the last
> 35 days.
>
> You can call DescribeContinuousBackups at a maximum rate of 10 times
> per second.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeContinuousBackups.html

```
DescribeContinuousBackupsRequest backupsRequest =
                DescribeContinuousBackupsRequest
                        .builder()
                        .tableName("table")
                        .build();

        DescribeContinuousBackupsResponse backupsResponse = dbClient.describeContinuousBackups(backupsRequest);

        if(backupsResponse.continuousBackupsDescription().pointInTimeRecoveryDescription().pointInTimeRecoveryStatus().equals("DISABLED")) {

            result = "false";
            failReason = "Continuous Backup is not enabled for DynamoDB Tables."
                    + "DynamoDB table without backup can result in accidental data loss. Your AWS DynamoDB tables should make use of Point-in-time Recovery "
                    + "(PITR) feature in order to automatically take continuous backups of your DynamoDB data.";
            offenders.add("Table Name: " + tablesResponse.tableNames());

        }
```

Reference:  https://github.com/harshangp20/dynamoDBAudit/blob/094041168f6d105675f376c31275074b2c1dea45/src/main/java/org/lambda/service/DynamoDBCheckList.java#L317

Answer (score 0):

```
DescribeContinuousBackupsRequest backupsRequest = DescribeContinuousBackupsRequest
             .builder().tableName("table").build();

DescribeContinuousBackupsResponse backupsResponse = dbClient.describeContinuousBackups(backupsRequest);

if(backupsResponse.continuousBackupsDescription().pointInTimeRecoveryDescription().pointInTimeRecoveryStatus().equals("DISABLED")) {

   result = "false";
   failReason = "Continuous Backup is not enabled for DynamoDB Tables."
         + "DynamoDB table without backup can result in accidental data loss. Your AWS DynamoDB tables should make use of Point-in-time Recovery "
         + "(PITR) feature in order to automatically take continuous backups of your DynamoDB data.";
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, can you explain why your code can fix the issue and answer to question ?